# UIScrollView needs a touch before I can scroll

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a really strange behavior of my UIScrollView. It needs a touch before it can scroll, so it scrolls first on the second touch.

I set the ContentSize in the LayoutSubview, so I can see that the content size is bigger than its size (it also show the scrollview indicator) when the scrollview is loaded.

Any ideas why this happends?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this behavior can be fixed by set content delay touch to `NO`.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. The parent view is a UIImageView with user interaction = YES. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: You mean using myScrollView.Layer.content = (id)someImage?

Comment: No, I mean make UIImageView and UIScrollView to be subview of the same superview, and place UIImageView behind UIScrollView.